# JMS Transaction manager not working in camel client code

Tags: spring, apache-camel, jms-topic

I have simple code which connects to broker URL using TCP . When i set transaction manager my code completes without exception and no messages are consumed but when i don't set traction manager it works fine.

Following is code , i am not getting what is missing or is there any configuration needs to be done on broker host.

```
    import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ConsumerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager;


public class JmsCamelComponent {
    public void getMessage() {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                "tcp://10.10.3.140:61616?jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries=10");
        JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager(jmsConnectionFactory);
        JmsConfiguration config = new JmsConfiguration(jmsConnectionFactory);
        config.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
        JmsComponent jms = new JmsComponent(config);
        jms.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager);
        jms.setTransactionTimeout(1000000);
        try {
            System.out.println("Creating and adding route...");
            context.addComponent("jms", jms);
            context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                public void configure() {
                    System.out.println("Inside configure...");
                    from("jms:topic:prathamq?clientId=411&durableSubscriptionName=parag").to("file://test2");
                    System.out.println("after getting message");
                }
            });
            ConsumerTemplate template = context.createConsumerTemplate();
            context.start();
            System.out.println("Context started...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(" " + template.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("In catch block");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new JmsCamelComponent()).getMessage();
    }
}
```

Following line i set or unset "jms.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager);"
Please help.
Thanks in adavnce ,
Sohan

Comment: You do realise that the call to System.out.println("after getting message"); won't actually print after you process a message?

Comment: It gets printed, but my question is that why i dont receive messages from queue when i connect to broker URL. It there anything i need to add in code?

Comment: I asked because it says "after getting message" but it will actually be printed after the config is running and isn't anything to do with the message. Next question are: what are you trying to do with the consumer template as it doesn't seem to do anything useful; how are you checking whether you get a message or not? Are you just looking in file test2?

Comment: Ye you are right. Yes i am checking in file test2 whcih gets created on my disk.
But when i set property of transaction it creates problem.

Comment: ok, i'll see if i can reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've re-produced the problem (after a few false starts) and got a version that works:

```
public void getMessage() throws Exception {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
    JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager(jmsConnectionFactory);

    SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
    registry.put("transactionManager", jmsTransactionManager);

    JmsConfiguration config = new JmsConfiguration(jmsConnectionFactory);
    config.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);

    JmsComponent jms = new JmsComponent();
    jms.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager);

    context.getRegistry();
    context.addComponent("jms", jms);

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("activemq:topic:matt?clientId=411&durableSubscriptionName=matt")
            .log("GOT A MESSAGE");
        }
    });
    context.start();
    System.out.println("Context started...");
    Thread.sleep(10000000);
}
```

Apart from increasing the thread sleep time to make sure the app doesn't exit before its had chance to do anything, the root cause was lack of a platform transaction manager in the registry. You need to create/get a registry and add the transaction manager to it.

If you're using Spring, you can just use the Spring context. In this example, I just create a SimpleRegistry to get the code to work.

If you take your failing code and add an explicit .transacted() in the route, you can see it complains about not finding a platform transaction manager. Why it doesn't complain without an explicit .transacted() call I don't know but that appears to be the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but did you try with setting route something like this, from("jms:topic:prathamq?clientId=411&durableSubscriptionName=sohanb").to("file://test2");. 

I guess it create problem with setting durableSubscription.

Comment: Could be (I would've posted by answer as a comment but the code formatting doesn't work), I'll give it a try. Are you able to run my code and see if you still get the same problem?

Comment: I tried ur code bu no luck. What ur doing to send messages ?

Comment: I'm using the activemq webconsole to add a message

Comment: Ok... it create problem when i set transaction manager as said earlier and that to for topic only. For queue it works fine.

Comment: We're slowing getting there! I can't try this as I'm at work but according to http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html, the JmsComponent should be created as JmsComponent component = JmsComponent.jmsComponentTransacted(connectionFactory, transactionManager); which could be worth a try

Comment: I Tried this earlier,tried again .. still no luck. Try out on ur side when you are free. Thanks